# "Adobe Business Catalyst" Multi level Liquid Menu

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

Any one can help me to create multi level menu in Adobe business catalyst.

Here is single level menu code:

```
{module_menu render="collection" menuId="1425822" template="" collection="menu2"}
<ul>
  {% if menu2.items %} 
  {% for i in menu2.items %}
  <li class="{{i.CSS class name}}"><a href="{{i.url}}">{{i.label}}</a> </li>
  {% endfor %}  
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just like that : )


   {module_menu render="collection" menuId="1558121" template="" collection="menu1"}
                <ul>
                    {% if menu1.items %}
                    {% for i in menu1.items %}
                            <li class="has-sub"><a href="{{i.url}}">{{i.label}}</a>{% if i.items %}
                                <ul>
                                    {% for j in i.items %}
                                    <li><a href="{{j.url}}">{{j.label}}</a> {% if j.items %}
                                        <ul>
                                            {% for k in j.items %}
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{{k.url}}">{{k.label}}</a>
                                            </li>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                                {% endif %}
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
```